# Substitute char array with std::string in an input parameter to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, char

Following are two legacy routines. I cannot change the routine declarations.

```
static bool GetString(char * str);        //str is output parameter
static bool IsStringValid(const char * str);    //str is input parameter
```

With call as follows

```
char inputString[1000];

GetString(inputString);

IsStringValid(inputString);
```

Instead of using fixed char array, I want to use std::string as the input. I am not able get the semantics right (string::c_str).

Comment: `GetString` is as bletcherous as `gets(char *)`, so I hope the legacy engineer that wrote that legacy function is... history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `IsEmpty` it should not be a problem:

```
std::string str = "Some text here";
IsEmpty(str.c_str());
```

Though it's pretty useless if you have a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) as then you would normally just call [`str.empty()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty).

---

The other function though, that's harder. The reason is that it's argument is not `const`, and `std::string` doesn't allow you to modify the string using a pointer.

It *can* be solved, by writing a wrapper-function which takes a string reference, and have an internal array used for the actual `GetString` call, and uses that array to initialize the passed string reference.

---

Wrapper examples:

```
// Function which "creates" a string from scratch
void GetString(std::string& str)
{
    char tempstr[4096];
    GetString(tempstr);
    str = tempstr;
}

// Function which modifies an existing string
void ModifyString(std::string& str)
{
    const size_t length = str.size() + 1;
    char* tempstr = new char[length];
    std::copy_n(str.c_str(), tempstr, length);

    ModifyString(tempstr);

    str = tempstr;
    delete[] tempstr;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, got all of you confused. IsEmpty(), was just an example name, it doesn't check for emptyness per se

Comment: @ontherocks It doesn't matter. If a function takes a `const char*` argument, you can use [`c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) like I shown.

Comment: So, do I need some wrapper or I can directly use reference to string on GetString(). Like `std::string str; GetString(&str);`

Comment: @ontherocks First of all, using `&str` makes a pointer or type `std::string*`, not the same as you want. For functions taking non-const character pointer (and presumably modifies the strings) you have to make wrappers.

Comment: Please provide an example wrapper for GetString

Comment: @ontherocks Added a couple of example functions

Comment: So, it seems I cannot get away with pre allocating a fixed size, which was the sole reason to move to string

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `c_str` for the first function, because it returns a `const char*`. You can pass a `std::string` by reference and assign to it. As for is empty, you can call `c_str` on your string, but you'd be better of calling the member `empty()`.

Comment: Sorry, got all of you confused. IsEmpty(), was just an example name, it doesn't check for emptyness per se

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the string container of STL ( Standard template Library ) .

```
  #include <string>
  bool isempty ( int x ) {
    return ( x == 0 ) ? true : false ;     
  }
  // inside main()

  string s ;
  cin >> s ; // or getline ( cin , s) ;
  bool empty = isEmpty (s.length()) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` has `c_str()` which you can use for `IsEmpty`. There ist no function which gives you a non const pointer. Since std::string's allocation is not guaranteed to be contiguous you cannot do something like `&s[0]` either. The only thing you can do is to use a temporary char buffer as you do in your example.

```
std::string s;
char inputString[1000];
std::vector<char> v(1000);

GetString(inputString);
GetString(&v[0]);

s = &v[0];
IsEmpty(s.c_str());
```

Comment: In C++11 strings are guaranteed to be contiguous and there is still no  direct modifiable access to the elements. And all implementations of `std::string` I have seen use contiguous allocation anyways.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Oh I did't know this. But when it's contiguous, why don't I have modifiable access like I have with `vector`?

Comment: I should have been more explicit, there is no way to directly obtain a pointer to modifiable data, although you can still do `&str[0]`. Why? I wasn't there, but that is what the standard says.